# How to create response schema in exported swagger json from API in Azure API Management Service?

Tags: powerapps, power-automate-custom-connector

- I have created API endpoints in Azure API management service and exported it as swagger.json file.
- The export is to be consumed to create Connector in PowerApps.
- Swagger file from API export contains response example which I entered manually in API endpoint definition.
- Connector imports all the requests bodies correctly but fails to load sample response body.

My ultimate goal is to added sample response body to the connector's action automatically. I do not want to re-enter sample response body manually in the connector.

Endpoint schema from APIM (exported swagger.json file):

```
"/Patient/{id}": {
        "get": {
            "description": "/Patient/{id} - GET",
            "operationId": "get-patient-id",
            "summary": "/Patient/{id} - GET",
            "parameters": [{
                "name": "id",
                "in": "path",
                "description": "id of resource",
                "required": true,
                "type": "string"
            }],
            "produces": [
                "application/json"
            ],
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "Success",
                    "example": {
                        "application/json": {
                            "resourceType": "Patient",
                            "id": "53",
                            "gender": "female",
                            "birthDate": "1989-07-30"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Endpoint schema from another Powerapps custom connector (swagger export):

```
"/Patient/{id}": {
  "get": {
    "operationId": "get-patient-id",
    "summary": "/Patient/{id} - GET",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "id",
        "in": "path",
        "description": "id of resource",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Success",
        "schema": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "resourceType": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "resourceType"
            },
            "id": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "id"
            },
            "gender": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "gender"
            },
            "birthDate": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "birthDate"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you mean that you wanna this place has the same default response as you added in apim? https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ6nk.png

Comment: Yes, you could say so. But it would be better if it is in 200 status written just above.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that apim doesn't provide choice to fill the default response in the powerapp connector when exporting. I'm afraid that the default response in power app could only modify manually.